# Deriving confidence interval for random-effect model

Tags: regression, mixed-model, confidence-interval, random-effects-model, linear

In R, when using the usual linear regression functions, such as `lm()`, deriving and plotting confidence bands are easily done with the `predict()` function. However, I'm using a slightly more complex linear regression, which is a random-effect Tobit (censored) model (`censReg()` from the package `censReg`) and the `predict()` cannot be applied for this package. In this case, I have to calculate it "manually".
I found some very clear expanation on how such confidence bands can be derived in R for any fixed-effect model (see [this page](https://rpubs.com/aaronsc32/regression-confidence-prediction-intervals)):

[image: Confidence band]

However, I did not find such formula for a linear mixed (or random) effect model. But, as the `predict()` function also exists for random-effect models in the `lm()`, such a formula should exist. Does anyone know this formula and is there any R package that calculates it for any (linear) model if we give the right information (i.e. giving the covariates x, the fitted $\hat{y}$ and the variance parameter of the random effect)?

Comment: Hi, have you also tried the good old confint() function? Just like this: outcome<-censreg(whatever)                      confint(outcome)

Comment: Hi Claudio, the confint() function gives the confidence interval of the parameters based on the log-likelihood curvature. What I want is the confidence interval of $\hat{y}$, the outcome.

Comment: Oh, my apologies, I misunderstood